# How do I register a class/object as listener for object life-cycle events after the ServerRuntime has been built?

Tags: java, apache-cayenne

The Cayenne docs shows how to use ServerRuntimeBuilder to register as a listener for object life-cycle events with something like this:

```
ServerRuntime.builder()
             .addConfig("cayenne-model.xml")
             .addModule(binder -> ServerModule.contributeDomainListeners(binder)
                                              .add(MyListener.class))
             .build();
```

How do I register for those events later, when the ServerRuntime has already been created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After startup a listener can be added to the DataDomain directly:

```
ServerRuntime rt = ..
rt.getDataDomain().addListener(new MyListener());
```

Comment: Thank you Andrus. I had tried that but for some reason by using a static method. It works perfectly now.